# How do I find this eigenvector for a symmetric Matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I have a symmetric matrix A, whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 6,~ \lambda_2 = 3,~ \lambda_3 = 2$ and eigenvectors are $\vec{v_1} = (1, 1, 1),~\vec{v_2} = (1,1,-1)$. How do I find the third eigenvector $\vec{v_3}$?

Comment: Eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are pairwise orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Since the matrix is symmetric, (and real, I presume) it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: But how do I use this in practice?

Comment: By searching for a vector orthogonal to both $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$.

Comment: So, it would be okay to take the cross-product of both vectors, as in $\vec{v_3} = \vec{v_1} \times \vec{v_2}$ and the resulting $\vec{v_3} = (-3,3,0)$ would be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is.